# restarting application server in websphere without admin user/password

Tags: ibm-was

I have a requirement where I need to restart websphere application server without providing username/password with the startServer.sh/stopServer.sh

Also I don't want to disable the WebSphere administrative security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Configuring the soap.client.properties file](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFHJY_1.0.6/deploy/configure_the_soap.client.properties_file.dita) topic in the Knowledge Center.

Comment: @Vishroxxx Then you should click the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That give me reputation, and it improves your acceptance rate, which encourages people to answer your questions in the future.